# Repair a PDF file with unsupported filters

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

My code takes a list of PDF strings and combines creates PDFs by category. I am using PyPDF2 to combine and bookmark files. I am getting 'Unsupported PNG Filter 3' and 'Unsupported PNG Filter 4' when dealing with some files. I have found that if I manually open the file in Adobe and save over itself with the same name, the problem is corrected most of the time. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I can open the file but cannot figure out how to save and close it. Ideally this would run in the background.

```
def repair_file(self, path):
        #Open PDF
        subprocess.Popen([path], shell=True)
        #Want a way to simply save like this
        #subprocess.save([path], shell=True)
```

Alternatively, does anyone have a better solution for "repairing" files?

```
def repair_file(self, path):
        #Open PDF
        subprocess.Popen([path], shell=True)
        #subprocess.write([path], shell=True)

        #Tried
        #with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        #    f.write(path)
        #print('File Saved')

def combine_pdf(self, isos, pkg): #Unsupprted PNG Filter 4
        #Combine PDFs
        dir_name = r"E:\Test Folder\Y\Combined Isometrics"
        suffix = ".pdf"

        merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
        for iso in isos:
            path = os.path.join(dir_name, iso + suffix)
            print(pkg," : ",path)
            bookmark = iso

            try:
                merger.append(open(path, 'rb'),bookmark)

            except Exception as e:
                #self.repair_file(pdf)
                log = 'Error adding drawing: ' + str(pkg) + " : " + str(iso) + '\n' + '__Error: ' + str(e)
                line = ",".join(str(iso)+str(pkg)+str(e))
                stat = "Failed"

                self.add_line(stat,line)
                self.write2log(log) 

                try:
                    self.repair_file(path)
                    merger.append(open(path, 'rb'),bookmark)

                except Exception as e:
                #self.repair_file(pdf)
                    log = 'Error repairing: ' + str(pkg) + " : " + str(iso) + '\n' + '__Error: ' + str(e)
                    self.write2log(log) 
        try:
            merger.write(pkg + ".pdf")
            merger.close()
        except Exception as e:
            log = 'Error saving Package: ' + pkg + '\n' + '__Error: ' + str(e)
            self.write2log(log)
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: What's broken?  There are a number of very good command-line PDF tools available, like `cpdf` and `pdftk`.  Surely one of those can do the job.

Comment: So far, it has just been Unsupported  PNG Filter errors. Alot of these pdf files are marked up and edited before getting to me so I'm sure it has something to do with that.

Comment: I have tried using a couple different repair tools and just ended up corrupting the file from being able to open.

Comment: Couldn't add the PDF but the drawings are marked up like the attached edit using Bluebeam or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into a "filter" error as well. Using qpdf to copy all pages into a new file resolved it.

```
    qpdf --empty --pages infile.pdf -- outfile.pdf
```